# perl save utf-8 text problem

Tags: perl, utf-8, filehandle

I am playing around the pplog, a single file file base blog.

The writing to file code:

```
open(FILE, ">$config_postsDatabaseFolder/$i.$config_dbFilesExtension");

my $date = getdate($config_gmt);
print FILE $title.'"'.$content.'"'.$date.'"'.$category.'"'.$i;    # 0: Title, 1: Content, 2: Date, 3: Category, 4: FileName
print 'Your post '. $title.' has been saved. <a href="?page=1">Go to Index</a>';
close FILE;
```

The input text:

```
春眠不覺曉，處處聞啼鳥． 夜來風雨聲，花落知多小．
```

After store to file, it becomes:

```
春眠不覺�›�，處處聞啼鳥．  夜來風�›�聲，花落知多小．
```

I can use Eclipse to edit the file and make it render to normal. The problem exists during printing to the file.

Some basic info:
Strawberry perl 5.12
without use utf8;
tried use utf8;, dosn't have effect.

Thank you.

--- EDIT ---
Thanks for comments. I traced the code:

Codes add new content:

```
# Blog Add New Entry Page

    my $pass = r('pass');


        #BK 7JUL09 patch from fedekun, fix post with no title that caused zero-byte message...  
        my $title = r('title');
        my $content = '';
        if($config_useHtmlOnEntries == 0)
        {
            $content = bbcode(r('content'));
        }
        else
        {
            $content = basic_r('content');
        }
        my $category = r('category');
        my $isPage = r('isPage');

sub r
{
    escapeHTML(param($_[0]));
}
```

sub r forward the command to a CGI.pm function.

In CGI.pm

```
sub escapeHTML {
     # hack to work around  earlier hacks
     push @_,$_[0] if @_==1 && $_[0] eq 'CGI';
     my ($self,$toencode,$newlinestoo) = CGI::self_or_default(@_);
     return undef unless defined($toencode);
     $toencode =~ s{&}{&amp;}gso;
     $toencode =~ s{<}{&lt;}gso;
     $toencode =~ s{>}{&gt;}gso;
     if ($DTD_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER =~ /[^X]HTML 3\.2/i) {
     # $quot; was accidentally omitted from the HTML 3.2 DTD -- see
     # <http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html#bad-entity> /
     # <http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/1997Mar/0003.html>.
        $toencode =~ s{"}{&#34;}gso;
     }
     else {
        $toencode =~ s{"}{&quot;}gso;
     }

    # Handle bug in some browsers with Latin charsets
    if ($self->{'.charset'} 
            && (uc($self->{'.charset'}) eq 'ISO-8859-1'    # This line cause trouble. it treats Chinese chars as ISO-8859-1
            || uc($self->{'.charset'}) eq 'WINDOWS-1252')) {
                $toencode =~ s{'}{&#39;}gso;
                $toencode =~ s{\x8b}{&#8249;}gso;
                $toencode =~ s{\x9b}{&#8250;}gso;
        if (defined $newlinestoo && $newlinestoo) {
            $toencode =~ s{\012}{&#10;}gso;
            $toencode =~ s{\015}{&#13;}gso;
        }
    }
    return $toencode;
}
```

Further trace the problem, found out the browser default to iso-8859-1, even manually set to utf-8, it send the string back to server as iso-8859-1.

Finally,

```
print header(-charset => qw(utf-8)), '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

add the -charset => qw(utf-8) param to header. The Chinese poem is still Chinese poem.

Thanks for Schwern's comments, it inspired me to trace out the problem and learn a leeson.

Comment: Still no reproduceable test case, or even clear problem description. Displayed refusal to acknowledge attempts to help, apparently downvoting them. Downvoted in turn.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get utf8 really working in Perl involves flipping on a lot of individual features.  `use utf8` only makes your code utf8 (strings, variables, regexes...), you have to do file handles separately.

Its complicated, and the simplest thing is to use [utf8::all](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8%3a%3aall) which will make utf8 the default for your code, your files, @ARGV, STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR.  utf8 support is constantly improving in Perl, and utf8::all will add it as it comes available.

Comment: Tested all suggestion below, none working. Further dig into the code, the problem is cause by a regex on $content. Its not related to file handle.

Comment: @Weiyan: Then you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Weiyan You should try `use utf8::all` in the scope where $content is worked on. If you can track down the code which is actually mangling $content you should edit your question to show it, then we can help.

Comment: Greatest answer. It didn't give a straight forward answer, but inspired me to trace out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of how your code can produce that output—for example, the quote marks are missing. Of course, this could be due to "corruption" somewhere between your file and me seeing the page. SO may filter corrupted UTF-8. I suggest providing hex dumps in the future!

Anyway, to get UTF-8 output working in Perl, there are several approaches:

1. Work with character data, that is let Perl know that your variables contain Unicode. This is probably the best method. Confirm that `utf8::is_utf8($var)` is true (you do *not* need to, and *should not* `use utf8` for this). If not, look into the `Encode` module's `decode` function to make Perl know its Unicode. Once Perl knows your data is characters, that print will give warnings (which you do have enabled, right?). To fix, enable the `:utf8` or `:encoding(utf8)` layer on your file (the latter version provides error checking). You can do this in your open (`open FILE, '>:utf8', "$fname"`) or alternative enable it with binmode (`binmode FILE, ':utf8'`). Note that you can also use other encodings; see the `encoding` and `PerlIO::encoding` docs.
2. Treat your Unicode as opaque binary data. `utf8::is_utf8($var)` must be false. You must be very careful when manipulating strings; for example, if you've got UTF-16-BE, this would be a bad idea: `print "$data\n"`, because you actually need `print $data\0\n"`. UTF-8 has fewer of these issues, but you need to be aware of them.

I suggest reading the perluniintro, perlunitut, perlunicode, and perlunifaq manpages/pods.

Also, `use utf8;` just tells Perl that your script is written in UTF-8. Its effects are very limited; see its pod docs.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the code that is actually running. I successfully processed the text you supplied as input with both 5.10.1 on Cygwin and 5.12.3 on Windows. So I suspect a bug in your code. Try narrowing down the problem by writing a short, self-contained test case.

Comment: [link](http://code.google.com/p/pplog/downloads/list) The code has more than one thousand line, I only post the lines I think responsible to this operation.